# Dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller Error startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I follow step MVC in Microsoft Tutorial by VScode until to step Generate controllor and DBcontext follow this command

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name MoviesController -m Movie -dc MvcMovie.Data.MvcMovieContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries -sqlite
```

and error like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6674.png

I have already install package follow this

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

model file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGGxa.png

My dotnet --info

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.100
 Commit:    e12b7af219

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       d099f075e4

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info
```

My dotnet tool list -g

```
PS C:\MvcMovie> dotnet tool list -g
Package Id                       Version      Commands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator      7.0.0        dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet-ef                        7.0.0        dotnet-ef
```

My dotnet list package

```
PS C:\MvcMovie> dotnet list package
Project 'MvcMovie' has the following package references
   [net7.0]: 
   Top-level Package                                       Requested   Resolved
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore                         7.0.0       7.0.0
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design                  7.0.0       7.0.0
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite                  7.0.0       7.0.0
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer               7.0.0       7.0.0
   > Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design      7.0.0       7.0.0
```

I expect to generate controller and DBContext by aspnet-codegenerator controller

Comment: Target framework version and package's versions could matter. Check this link as a clue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26852#issuecomment-1190873645

Comment: Looks like a good candidate to report it as an issue on Github. Btw, your code works for me on all platforms MacOS/Windows/Ubuntu

Comment: This code it works for me too on macOS but on my PC Windows doesn't work